# windows extract all not working properly, trying to extract compressed content

Tags: windows-7, compression, zip, tar

for a colleague I have created a zip containing two projects, each having multiple docker images that are compressed to xx.tar inside them.
The idea is that I can give her a zip file of the whole folder. She then extracts this which should result in the following structure:

```
folder
 ├─project1
 │  ├─docker1.tar
 │  └─docker2.tar
 └─project2
    └─docker3.tar
```

I am creating this zip using `zip -er folder.zip` folder on my mac.
other unix and mac users have no problems with this but the windows users complain that there is not enough space on the drive, it requires 785PB(!) to extract.. what I can see is when I browse the zip on the windows machine is that it says the size of one of the .tar files is 785 PB for some reason..

why is windows behaving like this ?? the compressed tar is only 5.9gb.
should I create the zip differently ? create an sfx?
any ideas please?

Comment: Can you recreate the zip file to check if the current one is corrupted? Also, anyu pranksters in the office who know about sparse files?

Comment: nope, it wasnt corrupt. please see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known that the size of the file archived which size is more than 4GB is displayed incorrectly in Windows Explorer.
That happens because Windows Explorer (confirmed/tested on Windows 7) cannot process these archives correctly which is due to 64-bit file size data (zip64) being read incorrectly.

Info-ZIP UnZip (version 6.00 or newer) can process these archives correctly or any other good archiver like 7zip (free) or winrar.

So your issue is one of unpacker data interpretation, not a packing problem.

Comment: ok, thanks for the information. I built an sfx using 7zip that is working now but I wanted to know what the reasons behind it where.